# Kubernetes - How to check if the Pod in K8S is running as root (or) non-root?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Is there a flag/field in kubectl describe pods which tells if the container is running as root or non-root, I have few containers, I need to check if they are running as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `whoami` command inside the pod to see the name of the users. You can also check if `runAsUser` field is specified in the `securityContext` of pod's manifest. Containers by default run as root users.

For `securityContext`, check out examples in this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)

Comment: thanks, whoami was not available, I got the ID , it was 0, yes all process are running with 0, I am taking 0 as root

Answer (score 1):

You can check the user and group ID of the container running in a Pod by running the command `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- ps aux`. The first column of the output will show the user and group ID in the format `<user>/<group>`. If the user ID is 0, then the container is running as the root user. If the user ID is not 0, then the container is running as a non-root user.

You can also check the security context of a pod using the command `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>`. The output will include a section labeled "Security Context" which will indicate the user and group ID the pod is running as.

You can also use `kubectl get pod <pod-name> -o` jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].securityContext.runAsUser}' to check the user ID of the pod.